# ldap queries - need the dn of the users who are authenticated via ldap protocol and their IP address

Tags: active-directory, ldap, single-sign-on, ldap-query, federated-identity

LDAP/AD Experts,
It might be simple for you but its challenging task for me!.

****"ldap queries - need the dn of the users who are authenticated via ldap protocol and their IP address**"**
We are migrating authentication out of AD/LDAP.

We’re looking to migrate applications that are directly using AD for employees.
Its not specific to OU and Group but overall active directory.
We have plenty of applications which uses AD/LDAP for authentication.
How do I pull such data? At least need to have user details.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the DN of a user is easy with any ldapsearch utility.

There is no method to obtain "the users who are authenticated" from LDAP. You could find the "time" a user did last Authenticate, regardless of how, from the lastLogon or LastLogonTimeStamp.

Generally, the IP Address of the user is not available as part of the user entry within Microsoft Active Directory.

You might be able to obtain this from some power-shell script, but I was unable to find anything from a quick search.